# How to work with char* inside a class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, char

I am new to c++ and doing some self training from a text book.  I need to create a new class, "String".  It must use a constructor to initialize the string to a made up of a repeating character of a sepcified length.

I cannot figure out how to assign anything to a char* variable.  Per the assignment I CANNOT use the standard string library to do this.  What Do I need to do in my constructor?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class String {
  protected:
    int  _len;

  public:
      char *buff;
    String (int n, char* c);
};

int main()
{
  String myString(10,'Z');
  cout << myString.buff << endl;

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

String::String(int n, char* c)
{
  buff = new char[n];

}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the C string functions like `strlen`?

Comment: Hopefully the next chapter will teach you that you need a destructor, a copy constructor, and a copy assignment operator. Then the chapter after that will teach you never to use naked pointers. And the chapter after that will teach you to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there: since you need repeated character, you shouldn't be passing `char*`, just a plain `char`. Also buffers of C strings need to be longer by one character than the string; the last element of the buffer must be the zero character `\0`.

```
String::String(int n, char c) {
    buff = new char[n+1];
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; buf[i++] = c)
        ;
    buf[n] = '\0';
}
```

Note that making `buf` a public member variable is not a good idea: users of `String` shouldn't be able to reassign a new buffer, so providing an accessor `char* c_str()` and making `buf` private is probably a good idea.

Comment: On that same train of thought, the `c_str` function better be returning `char const*`.